# How can I add a list item to my URL structure within a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, bioinformatics

So I'm new to Python and am working on a simple program that will read a text file of protein names (PDB IDs) and create a URL to search a database (the PDB) for that protein and some associated data.

Unfortunately, as a newbie, I forgot to save my script, so I can't recall what I did to make my code work!

Below is my code so far:

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import os

os.chdir("C:\\PythonProjects\\Samudrala Lab Projects")

protein_file = open("protein_list.txt","r")
protein_list = protein_file.read()

for item in protein_list:
    item = item[0:4]
    query_string =urlencode('customReportColumns','averageBFactor','resolution','experimentalTechnique','service=wsfile','format=csv')
    **final_URL = url + '?pdbid={}{}'.format(url, item, query_string)**
    print(final_URL)
```

The line of code I'm stuck on is starred.

The object "final_url" within the loop is missing some modification to indicate that I'd like the URL to search for the item as a pdbid. Can anyone give me a hint as to how I can tell the URL to plug in each item on the list as a PDBID?

I'm getting a type error indicating that it's not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object. Original post was edited to add this info.

Please let me know if this is an unclear question, or if you need any additional info.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `url` defined

Comment: Oops, I didn't include that here for some reason. I am defining the URL before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
final_URL = "{}?pdbids={}{}".format(url, item, query_string)
```

Comment: Hmmmm, when I try that, I get a Type Error. Let me play around with your idea, though! Thanks!

Comment: Can you send me more of your code please? It'd be handy to try debugging it locally

Comment: Yes, I'll add it to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a line from protein_list.txt please? It's difficult to test without any data

Comment: Here's one: 3f8vA

Comment: `query_string =urlencode('customReportColumns','averageBFactor','resolution','experimentalTechnique','service=wsfile','format=csv')` doesn't look right to me. What should the query string look like?

Comment: I'm currently working on that. I'm not sure about 'customreportcolumns','service=wsfile', or 'format=csv'. They may go somewhere else, like in the final_url object. Here's an example URL that I've been using: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/results/customReport.xml?pdbids=5d6sA&customReportColumns=averageBFactor,resolution,experimentalTechnique&service=wsfile&format=csv

Comment: how about `query_string =urlencode({'customReportColumns':'averageBFactor,resolution,experimentalTechnique','service':'wsfile','format':'csv'})`?